# problem with usb-c on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: video, usb-c

Notebook - HP HP ProBook 430 G7

Graphics - Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (CML GT2)

OS - Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

```
inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Cheng Uei Precision Industry (Foxlink) HP Wide Vision HD
    Integrated Webcam
    type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Device-3: USB C Video Adaptor type: USB driver: N/A
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 1: 1920x1080~60Hz
    2: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5
```

---

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 9636:9311 USB C   USB C Video Adaptor
```

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

**but the monitor via usb c does not work (no signal). maybe the problem is that the N/A driver? what to do?**

Answer (score 0):

As weird as it may seem, HP decided to "compensate" the lack of USB-C alternate mode with a very unusual internal DisplayLink device. Unusual because we typically find DisplayLink chipsets in docking stations and similar external devices.

So yes, you need drivers: https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1944022-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu-20-0

And you may need to disable Secure Boot on UEFI or use MOKutil to manually sign the drivers.

Comment: something didn't work for me :(

1. sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.6.1-59.184.run 
WARNING: Version 1.12.0 of EVDI kernel module is already running.
Please uninstall all other versions of DisplayLink Linux Software before attempting to install.
Installation terminated.
2. sudo apt update - done
3. sudo apt install dkms - done
4. sudo apt install libdrm-dev - done 
5. reboot
6. inxi -G
  Device-3: USB C Video Adaptor type: USB driver: N/A

Comment: Is your Ubuntu factory installed? Are you running a dual-boot with Windows 11? If not hen you can and arguably should disable Secure Boot in UEFI. It prevents loading of unsigned drivers like the DisplayLink ones that according to the error message are apparently installed already? Hence the question about Ubuntu being preinstalled.

Comment: I haven`t Windows, only Ubuntu. My BIOS settings = Legacy Soft Enabled and Secure Boot Disabled

Comment: the problem turns out to be that I have vendor code 9636 on usb, and displaylink works with vendor code 17e9. although windows works with vendor code 9636

Comment: Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode is is first mistake? WHY do you think enabling and installing Legacy mode is a good idea in 2022? A decade after the real BIOS disappeared to be replaced by UEFI or 8 years after the last OS without UEFI support (Windows XP) was discontinued? Really, it's baffling. And all bets are off. The root of the problem can well be just that.